# return first model ember js template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an ember js router that retrieves a list of models.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('article');
  }
});
```

I want to get the first model in the list inside my template, so I tried :

```
{{ article-preview article=model.[0] }}
```

but that didn't work, the article-preview component didn't receive the article model.

I tried this to see if the problem is in the component `article-preview`, but that worked.

```
  {{#each model as |article|}}
       {{ article-preview article=article}}
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
{{article-preview article=model.firstObject}}
```

[`firstObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#property_firstObject) retrieves the first object in an Ember Enumerable.